# javascript regular expression - removing comments

Tags: javascript, regex

The example is from [eloquent javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html#p_Q5tdrWs0Tm) book.Although There's a little explanation in the book it's really hard to follow, can anyone explain it from beginner perspective.I am having hard time to follow which slash is for what.

```
function stripComments(code) {
  return code.replace(/\/\/.*|\/\*[^]*\*\//g, "");
}
```

Comment: A nice way to try and understand a regular expression is to use something like [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/zTRRGwdDUjSn1wLj)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comment can have two forms:

```
// this is a comment
/* this is a comment */
```

Unfortunately, both `/` and `*` are special characters in regular expressions, so they must be escaped.

So we start with an empty match expression

```
//g
```

We set it to match the first form, `//` followed by any number of characters, which would be `//.*` but the slashes have to be escaped

```
/\/\/.*/g
```

The other form, `/*` followed by anything followed by `*/` is `/*[^]**/` but we have to escape the literal slashes and asterisks

```
\/\*[^]*\*\/
```

The two forms are then combined with a `|` character which denotes a "or":

```
\/\/.*|\/\*[^]*\*\/
```

and inserted into the empty regex

```
/\/\/.*|\/\*[^]*\*\//g
```

Comment: I like the step-by-step build-up approach. Much easier to follow than trying to grok it left-to-right.

Comment: Because these are not literal asterisks characters but mean "any number of the previously defined character". `.` in regex means "any character", thus `.*` means "any number of any character".

Comment: using `\/\*[^]*?\*\/` instead of `\/\*[^]*\*\/`  to perform minimum match, in case there are multiple comments

Answer (score 2):

First and last slashes are delimiters.

`g` at the end is a modifier (Modifiers are used to perform case-insensitive and global searches) and performs a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

`|` means **OR**.

`\/\/.*` has some escaped chars and can be translated as `// followed by any characters`
`\/\*[^]*\*\/` has also some escaped chars and can be translated as `/*any characters*/`

**Note**: both `/` and `*` must be escaped because they are used by regex syntax (special characters). So `\/` means `/` and `\*` means `*` while `.*` means any characters (0 or more times)

Since the goal of your code is to remove comments, all comments like `// xxxx` or `/* xxx */` are replaced by empty string

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down with one token per line:

```
/    # Start a new regex

# This group of tokens matches comments in the form:
# // this is a comment

\/   # An escaped forward slash
\/   # An escaped forward slash
.*   # Any character, zero or more times

|    # OR. This means "match either the previous or the next group of tokens".

# This group of tokens matches comments in the form:
# /* 
#  This is a comment, which could include some new lines
# */

\/   # An escaped forward dlash
\*   # An escaped asterisk
[^]* # A newline, zero or more times
\*   # An escaped asterisk
\/   # An escaped forward slash

/    # Finish the current regex.
g    # This regex can match multiple times against a given input
```

Answer (score 1):

/ --> start of regex

/ --> escaped "/" character

/ --> escaped "/" character

.* --> any character (even empty) --> here is the case // abck

| --> OR

/ --> escaped "/" character

* --> escaped "*" character

[^]* --> any character (multiline, so even \n\r)

* --> escaped "*" character

/ --> escaped "/" character --> here is the case /* aasd\nasdasd */

/ --> end of regex

g --> global modifier